# Send message from Phone (Android) to PC(Windows)

Tags: c#, android

i have a requirement to send a message (for example "Hello World !" in string format) from my application running on Android Phone to a application (C#/Windows application) running on a PC/Laptop on Windows 7 platform?

Any idea how to achieve this please?

thanks
Venu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create UDP socket between Android & PC and that's all.
Or you can use XMPP for example.

Comment: thanks. to use UDP they should be connected or on same network isn't it.

Comment: In simple case - YES. But, for travers NAT we should use STUN/TURN protocols.

Also you can use XMPP - it allows to exchange messages between users   from any platforms - there are a lot of free servers, e.g. http://quickblox.com . It has Chat module - http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat